# Why does chat make random POST requests?

Tags: support, chat

I noticed that in chat, I get random POST requests, to SE sites that I'm on. For example, as I type this question, it sends a POST request to

```
http://meta.stackexchange.com/gps/event
```

If I'm flagging spam on drupal.SE I get this

```
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/gps/event
```

What's this for? Is it just here to eat up my internet?

Comment: @James that also has no answer

Comment: "that also has no answer" no, but it *could potentially* have. And then that is likely to answer your question here ;)

Comment: I wrote an answer on the duplicate